# Returning table in assembler

Tags: c#, assembly

I'm having some troubles with my asm function. Here is the code:

```
afterModulo PROC stdcall uses edx tab:DWORD, ile:DWORD, e:DWORD, n:DWORD
LOCAL tabEnd:DWORD

mov EAX, tab
add EAX, ile
mov tabEnd, EAX

forLoop:
    mov EDX, [EAX]
    push EAX
    push n
    push e
    push EDX
    call powerModulo
    mov EDX, EAX
    pop EAX
    mov [EAX], EDX
    inc EAX
    cmp EAX, tabEnd
    jge exitLoop
    jmp forLoop
exitLoop:
    ret
afterModulo ENDP
```

I want to return modified table stored in EAX. Here is how i call asm function in C#:

```
 [DllImport("bibliotekaASM.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int[] afterModulo(int[] tab, int ile, int e, int n);

 public int[] wywolajFunkcjeAfter(int[] tab, int ile, int e, int n) 
    {
        return afterModulo(tab, ile, e, n);
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, i got this error: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in GUI.exe*
I'm sure it's return value issue(I've never worked on tables in assembler)

Comment: You cannot just return an array from pinvoke mode to managed mode.  You have to marshal it.  Hopefully someone will post an answer showing how to marshal it, but in the mean time, you better start reading about pinvoke marshalling.

Comment: If somebode can post an answer I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Only focussing on the assembly:

Your first read is past the end of the table! Use

```
mov EAX, tab
add EAX, ile
mov tabEnd, EAX
mov EAX, tab
forLoop:
```

Since it's a table of DWORDS you need to change the address by 4 in stead of 1.

```
mov [EAX], EDX
add EAX, 4
cmp EAX, tabEnd
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i haven't noticed that.